# Nuxt.js: async fetch declares b-modals twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

Maybe I'm not understanding well enough how nuxt works, but apparently my b-modals (bootstrap vue) are being declared twice whenever I use *async fetch* on a page. I'll explain how my code is structured (can't upload all of the code because of company policies):

I have a default layout in the *layouts* folder.

```
<template>
 <div>
  <wrapper-navbar />
  <nuxt class="body" />
  <wrapper-footer />
 </div>
</template>
```

Very simple stuff. The wrappers are declared in my components folder. The *wrapper-navbar* is a normal bootstrap navbar with modifications, and there I declare a *b-modal* with the unique id *#login-modal* which gets called whenever a user wants to login pressing a button with the attribute *v-b-modal.login-modal*. Everything works as expected, the user clicks the login button and a modal appears. The problem comes when in a page (in the *pages* folder) I call *async fetch()*. In these cases, when the user presses the login button, the login modal **appears twice**. I noticed that in these pages the methods *created()* and *mounted()* get called twice too, so I think that somehow the modal is getting declared twice.

```
// Inside pages/index.vue for example
async fetch() {
  try {
    this.data = await getSomeAsyncData();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

This only happens when I have an await inside it. If I only print something or just avoid using fetch, the modal just appears once. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this? Thanks for your feedback.